# Autocomplete css class in html not working in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The autocomplement in html of the names of the css classes stopped working.

I have tried many extensions, but nothing has worked:

- IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML
- HTML CSS Support

Also, gere's my `settings.json`

```json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "css.fileExtensions": [
        "css",
        "scss"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you share with us the config file? Also the problem could be caused by an extension you installed recently so you could try uninstalling extensions and adding them one by one to check if any of them stops the code snippets.

Comment: @nasck, if you're having trouble with extensions not working, you can use the [**extension bisect**](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) feature to figure out which one is causing the issue

Answer (score 4):

The recent updates of the HTML CSS Support extension had some errors which it doesn't support and find local & libraries' CSS classes, the current update of the extension is 1.6.0, I don't know if this version works or not but the safest version for this to work is 0.2.3.

In vscode you would have to click on the gear icon on the extension tab - Install another version ... and choose 0.2.3 if the current version doesn't work. After that either restart your vscode windows or restart your computer. This should work

Answer (score 0):

**Or you can add this to** `settings.json`

```json
"css.styleSheets": ["**"]
```

**Also `v1.13.1` works fine!**

Versions above `v1.13.1` have this problem!

*I had this problem today*