# CSS intellisense does not work after vscode update

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I have upgraded vs code and first Prettier was not formatting, fixed but now it does not show bootstrap classes when I `ctrl + space` , normally i was showing like this; 
[image: snippet]

NOTE: ***I have removed and reinstalled "HTML CSS Support" extension on VS Code so.*** still does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove and install again 'IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML' here is the link, you could follow the guide to use it. ;)

`https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion`

Comment: Thank you for your solution and it works. But not same as the picture I posted in the question. I will keep looking for solutions for this issue, and I dont think i will update vs code again...

Comment: Maybe you should install some (other) vsCode extension ?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65503147/11382670

According to @Jason Chuot, switching to version 0.2.3 still works. The extension in my question called as "HTML CSS Support". which wasnt working for me at the latest version. Now, I switched to 0.2.3 and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution regarding your problem because i had the same problem.
If you have HTML CSS Support installed in vscode, go to the extension tab, click on HTML CSS Support, click on the gear icon next to 'uninstall', click extension settings then click the edit settings.json from the "CSS: Style Sheets" delete the already existing css.stylesheets and paste this in:

```
"css.styleSheets": [
        
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "src/**/*.scss",
        "src/view/style.ts",
        "dist/style.css"
    ]
}
```

After that save the settings and you should be good to go :). I hope i could help you with this if you couldn't find a solution yet :).